# Unable to fetch record from StandardController - OnChange of Inputfield

Tags: apex, visualforce, standardcontroller

I have VF page where there is lookup field e.g. XYZ. After selcting a record from XYZ, I want to automatically render ABC record related to XYZ, where ABC is an Inputfield. I have written method called `onchange` of that XYZ lookup field.

Now I want to access the value in the XYZ input field to use that in my SOQL query to get its related record i.e. ABC record. BUT I am not getting the record values in that method. Not even in constructor (obvious). I have taken `StandardController` of the object too.

Comment: It's hard to give you an answer with the limited data you gave us.  Did you bind the data to your controller?  This should be the simplest way.

Comment: The onchange event Property where will you use either Script/Controller

Comment: Nilesh, you'll have to share your code with us, it's very hard to understand without it. Are you using remote javascript or plain rerendering/action methods ?

Comment: No JavaScript, its just one VF page and its and extension controller. Lets make it simple - Can I fetch the value of my Inputfield in the controller of the same page ?

Comment: @All ---- It was required field (field ABC) and I just had to make it outputField instead of inputfield. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can achieve by using Action Function Easily.
Below is the VF page using standard Task controller with extension and I am taking Account lookup value and passing it to extension to use in SOQL for selecting related contacts, and populating related contacts in VF page. Hope this will help you.

```
<apex:page standardController="Task" extensions="Test1Ext" id="thepage">

<script>

function fetchContactDetails(acc){
    fetchContact(document.getElementById('thepage:frm:pb:pbsection:whatidfield_lkid').value);

}
</script>

<apex:form id="frm" >
<apex:actionFunction name="fetchContact" action="{!createavailableContactList}" rerender="contacts" immediate="true">
<apex:param name="accountid" value=""/>
</apex:actionFunction>


<apex:pageBlock id="pb" >

<apex:pageBlockButtons id="pbb" >

    <apex:commandButton action="{!Save}" value="Save" />
    <apex:commandButton action="{!Cancel}" value="Cancel"/>       

</apex:pageBlockButtons>

   <apex:pageblockSection id="pbsection">

        <apex:inputField value="{!Task.WhatId}" onchange="fetchContactDetails()" onselect="fetchContactDetails()" id="whatidfield"/>
        <apex:pageblockSectionItem >
        <apex:outputLabel value="Contact"  />
        <apex:selectList value="{!contactselected}"  id="contacts" size="1">
        <apex:selectOptions value="{!ContactList}"/>
        </apex:selectList> </apex:pageblockSectionItem>                           
        <apex:inputField value="{!Task.ActivityDate}" />
        <apex:inputField value="{!Task.Description}" />                     


  </apex:pageblockSection>
</apex:pageBlock>

</apex:form>
```

Extension code:

public with sharing class Test1Ext {

```
public string contactselected{get;set;}    
public List<Contact> availableContactList { get; set;}
public List<SelectOption>  ContactList {get;set;}

public Test1Ext(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
ContactList = new List<SelectOption>();
ContactList.add(new SelectOption('','--None--'));

}

 public void createavailableContactList(){
    ContactList.clear();
    availableContactList = [Select id, Name from Contact where Accountid =:Apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('accountid') ];


     for(integer i=0;i<availableContactList.size();i++)   {
       ContactList .add(new SelectOption(availableContactList[i].id,availableContactList[i].Name));
     }





}
```

}